# python pandas get average of rows in dataframe that match two exact strings

Tags: string, pandas, dataframe, average

I have a pandas dataframe that is formatted like this:

```
Out[26]: 
      sub type window    mean   stdev     rms
0     S03   e4     w1 -0.6357  0.3274  0.7150
1     S03   e4     w1 -0.5910  0.3106  0.6676
2     S03   e4     w1 -0.4616  0.3607  0.5857
3     S03   e4     w1 -0.4570  0.3387  0.5687
4     S03   e4     w1 -0.5737  0.2689  0.6335
5     S03   e4     w1 -0.4818  0.2139  0.5271
6     S03   e4     w1 -0.4272  0.1523  0.4536
11    S03   e4     w2 -0.4561  0.1891  0.4937
12    S03   e4     w2 -0.5572  0.2553  0.6128
13    S03   e4     w2 -0.6797  0.2366  0.7196
14    S03   e4     w2 -0.5741  0.1919  0.6053
  ...  ...    ...     ...     ...     ...
3786  S26   e4     w5  0.7540  0.0893  0.7593
3787  S26   e4     w5  0.7976  0.0913  0.8028
3788  S26   e4     w5  0.8569  0.2041  0.8808
3789  S26   e4     w5  0.8631  0.2867  0.9094
3790  S26   e4     w5  0.8421  0.3568  0.9145
3791  S26   e4     w5  0.8213  0.3814  0.9055
3792  S26   e4     w6  0.6712  0.3152  0.7414
3793  S26   e4     w6  0.6619  0.3250  0.7373
3794  S26   e4     w6  0.6697  0.4079  0.7840
3795  S26   e4     w6  0.7050  0.4316  0.8266

[3799 rows x 6 columns]
```

For each subject (e.g. S03 & S26 shown in preview above) I need to get the average of: mean, stdev, and rms for each window (windows 1, 2, 5 & 6 shown in preview).

The number of rows for each window varies across all subjects (e.g. window 1 could be 6 rows for S05, but 15 rows for S13).

So I need to check the subject string in column = 'sub' and the window string in column = 'window' to check if the rows belong to the same subejct and window, and then calculate the average values for the mean, stdev, and rms columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this could also work :

```
df.groupby(['sub', 'window']).agg([np.average])
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question this should work:

```
df.groupby(['sub', 'window']).agg({'mean':['mean'], 'stdev':['mean'],
    'rms': ['mean']})
```